# How to use one useRef for multiple components withou useCallback - react

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I am learning react and I struggle with the hooks.
I am recreating a slightly simplified project from udemy.
There are rows of items which you can add to cart. When pressing the "Add" button I receive the correct console.log for the item's ID but the issue lies with the input value where you can increase the number of items.
Pressing any of the buttons only logs the last (bottom) input's value.

```
    //////////////Menu.js//////////////////
     
    import Card from "../UI/Card";
    import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";
     
    const MEALS = [
      {
        id: "m1",
        name: "Sushi",
        description: "Finest fish and veggies",
        price: 22.99,
      },
      {
        id: "m2",
        name: "Schnitzel",
        description: "A german specialty!",
        price: 16.5,
      },
      {
        id: "m3",
        name: "Barbecue Burger",
        description: "American, raw, meaty",
        price: 12.99,
      },
      {
        id: "m4",
        name: "Green Bowl",
        description: "Healthy...and green...",
        price: 18.99,
      },
    ];
     
    const Menu = (props) => {
      return (
        <Card>
          <ul>
            <MenuItem MEALS={MEALS} />
          </ul>
        </Card>
      );
    };
     
    export default Menu;
     
     
     
     
    //////////////MenuItem.js//////////////////
     
     
    import { useRef } from "react";
    import Input from "../UI/Input";
     
    const MenuItem = (props) => {
      const amountInputRef = useRef();
     
      const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.id);
        console.log(amountInputRef.current.value);
      };
     
      const mealItem = props.MEALS.map((e) => {
        return (
          <form id={e.id} key={Math.random()} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <li>
              {`${e.name} --- ${e.description} --- #${e.price}`}
     
              <Input
                ref={amountInputRef}
                input={{
                  id: e.id,
                  type: "number",
                  min: "0",
                  max: "5",
                }}
              />
     
              <button className="small-btn">Add</button>
            </li>
          </form>
        );
      });
     
      return mealItem;
    };
     
    export default MenuItem;
     
     
     
    //////////////Input.js//////////////////
     
     
    import React from "react";
     
    const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
      return <input ref={ref} {...props.input} />;
    });
     
    export default Input;
```

I have tried to solve this on my own for hours. I asked ChatGPT plenty of questions and mostly received answers to use multiple refs. The chat provided some solutions but they did not work. I tried to get help from udemy but they are unwilling. The code looks very similar to the original exercise code but I have no clue why it is not working. I was advised to use multiple refs but this is not how it is done in the exercise.

I took a look at similar posts, useCallback is used in a similar example, but again this is not what is being used in the original app from udemy.

Here is a link to the files in git hub just in case.
[GitHub](https://github.com/faforus/maxcourse/)
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need multiple refs. Using a single ref for multiple inputs... how is that supposed to ever work? "I tried some other stuff but it didn't work" is not enough information to tell you what went wrong. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]. Show your attempts. This site is here for you to **learn how things work**. Not to get others to write code for you.

Comment: I do not know how it is supposed to work. I am just a beginner. I do not want people to write the code for me. I tried for many hours today and yesterday and I fail to understand the problem. The solutions that I get are not the ones used in the course that I study. I do not think that showing my attempts matter as they simply do not work. I do not have such understanding of the code as other people do as I just started my journey here.

Comment: Let me phrase it a different way then. The solution to the code you've shown is just to use one separate ref for each input. You then go on to "I've heard that and already tried it but it doesn't work" without showing your attempt. You also reference some course "that does it differently" which you also don't show any exmaple from. If you want a different answer then "just use multiple refs" you need to show some code from your failed attemps or the alternative solution you can't get working from the course.

Comment: The original project is located here - https://github.com/academind/react-complete-guide-code/tree/11-practice-food-order-app/code/12-finished
The useRef is being used in src/Meals/MealForm.js
MealForm is part of MealItem which is part of AvailableMeals. Input from the UI folder is also used.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre]. Referencing external resources in the comments is not in line with the site guidelines. The question should be self-contained.

Comment: key={Math.random()} this is a fatal mistake in your application as the key prop is used to identify an element amongst it's sibling so the key prop has to be a unique value using math.random won't be consistent between renders as it creates a new key on each render
use the index as the key if you are only going to add elements after the last  one introducing a new key value otherwise create a unique id prop for each object in that array using Crypto.randomUUID()

Comment: I will take the tour, thanks.
Thanks Ahmad. I was going to change it later. Math random was there at the moment to clear console from this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a ref is used in React, it's automatically assigned to a given element only when that element mounts (when it is added to the DOM). In other words, since you pass all your input elements the same ref, and the last input of your list is the last to be added to the DOM, the ref will always equal the last input element.

You should be creating a ref per `MenuItem`, where each `MenuItem` represents one meal with one input. In other words, you should be rendering a list of `MenuItems` (e.g. `MEALS.map((meal) => <MenuItem ... />)`.

Alternatively, the new React Docs have a section on how to manage a list of refs: https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#how-to-manage-a-list-of-refs-using-a-ref-callback. While this is also a valid approach, it's likely more brittle for your use case.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at it but I still believe that there must be a different solution. The guy in this course " React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux)
" Seems to be doing something different. I do not think we used this callback yet.. Do you think you could take a look at his project and tell me what I am failing to understand?
https://github.com/academind/react-complete-guide-code/tree/11-practice-food-order-app/code/12-finished
The refs are used in the meals folder.

Comment: Well the most glaring difference I see is that you are mapping `MEALS` within `MealItem` instead of it's parent component (which they call `AvailableMeals`). `MealItem` is supposed to represent a single Meal, so the mapping should be producing a list of `MealItem`s (instead of one large `MealItem` with everything in it). That way, each `Mealitem` actually manages its own ref, and you don't need to manage a list of refs manually. And despite the official documentation I linked above, that is actually the more idiomatic way of doing this in React.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to look at it. It might be the case. I will try to rewrite it and see how it goes. Much appreciated! And just to be 100% sure. Are you saying that the way it is done in the course I am studying is the better way than the one in your link?

Comment: I believe the technique covered in the link I shared is for the niche use case in that you actually *need* a list of refs, such as if you are manipulating only a subset of the refs or you have logic where refs may depend on each other. However, in your case, you don't necessarily need to manage a list of refs, you just need multiple refs based on the list. And the most idiomatic way of doing that is to have one ref for each item component, like it is shown in your course. While the link I shared is still a good resource, I shared it without fully understanding your issue.